# How to get element's index in list when using foldl

Tags: haskell

I have to code a function to calculate `(sum k=1 to n) (-1)^(k+1) * a_k` from list `[a_1,a_2,a_3,..a_n]` using `foldl`.

```hs
calculate list = foldl (\x xs -> 
    x + (xs * (-1)^(??? + 1))
    ) 0 list
```

I managed to write this code, but I don't have a clue what should replace `???`, how to get index of an element in given list.

Comment: Hint: use `zip`.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to comment by Willem, I managed to do this in this way:

```
calculate list = foldl (\x (index,el) -> 
    x + (el * (-1)^(1 + index))
    ) 0 (zip [1..length(list)] list)
```

For me, it's more readable one, because I'm newbie, I just posted it for others :)

Comment: You can use `zip [1..] list`, and thus work with an *infinite* list, since `zip` stops from the moment one of the lists is exhausted :)

Answer (score 5):

We can implement this in a more simple way. We can consider a infinite list where we repeat two functions: [**`id :: a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:id), and [**`negate :: Num a => a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:negate), and use [**`cycle :: [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:cycle) to construct an infinite list. So `cycle [id, negate]` will produce a list that looks like `[id, negate, id, negate, ...]`.

We can then use [**`zipWith`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) to zip the infinite list with the list of values, and use [**`($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36-) as "*zip function*", so we get:

```
Prelude> zipWith ($) (cycle [id, negate]) [1,4,2,5]
[1,-4,2,-5]
```

The finally we can use [**`sum :: Num a => [a] -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum) to sum up these values.

So we can define the function as:

```
calculate :: Num a => [a] -> a
calculate = sum . zipWith ($) (cycle [id, negate])
```

For example:

```
Prelude> calculate [1,4,2,5]
-6
```